# Using jquery.form.js ajaxSubmit() scrolls to the top of page after it succeeds. Is this normal?

Tags: jquery, forms

Hi I have managed to get my form to submit without reloading, using this plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/
And also with the regular .post() method however the browser always scrolls to the top. Is this normal?

```
$(document).ready(function()

{

// Temporary upload demo
    if ($("#breadcrumbs:contains('AdrianTest')").length)
    {

    $('form.ltpo-form').ajaxForm();
    $('form.ltpo-form').submit(function(event) { 
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
   });


    $('form.ltpo-form').submit(function() { 
        // submit the form 
        var options = { 
            data: { p_action: 'Save' },
            success:    function() { 
                alert('Success');
        } 
        }; 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
        // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
    event.preventDefault();
        return false; 
    });

    }
        ...
```

Comment: I believe that the issue is being caused by another script: jquery.single-ddm.pack.js (I removed one at a time to find out).
So this makes me ask: **why do scripts run again after the page has been submitted?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had problems n was because i was using the ajaxSubmit and ajaxForm inside a wrap function like your

```
 $('form.ltpo-form').submit(function() {
```

Comment: i want to add something.. in the case of this kind of plugins.. try to always update them. check the version on the main .js plugin n compare it with the one at [link](https://raw.github.com/malsup/form/master/jquery.form.js)

Answer (score 0):

the issue is being caused by another script: jquery.single-ddm.pack.js

```
(function(A){A.fn.singleDropMenu=function(C){var F;var E;var D=A.extend({timer:500,parentMO:null,childMO:null},C||{});this.each(function(){A("li",this).mouseover(function(){B();A("a",this).addClass(D.parentMO).siblings("ul").show()}).mouseout(function(){E=this;F=setTimeout(function(){B()},D.timer)});A("li ul li",this).mouseover(function(){if(D.childMO){A("a",this).addClass(D.childMO)}}).mouseout(function(){if(D.childMO){A("a",this).removeClass(D.childMO)}})});A(document).click(function(){B()});var B=function(){if(E&&F){A("a",E).removeClass(D.parentMO).siblings("ul").hide();clearTimeout(F);E=""}}}})(jQuery);
```

I am still interested in knowing how to stop this script from scrolling the page on ajaxSubmit...